# How to use ScalingFunctions for multiple superimposed histograms?

Tags: plotting, histograms

Consider the simple MWE

```
gaus = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10000];
pois = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[1], 10000];
Histogram[{gaus, pois}, {1}, "LogCount", PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

How can I use `ScalingFunctions` in a single plot in order to rescale **only** the histogram for the Poisson distribution, dividing the counts by, say, 100?

Comment: If it's just a simple scaling, it might be easiest to just scale the data points. Otherwise you'd also have to decide how to handle the two different axes that result from two different scaling functions

Comment: I'm curious about why you'd want to have the same bin width for samples from a discrete and a continuous distribution.  Is the continuous distribution to be used as an approximation to the discrete distribution?  Also, using a log scale for the vertical axis makes comparing distributions near impossible as one typically wants the area under the curves/bars to be the same.  That doesn't happen when using a log scale.

Comment: @JimB Probably I used the wrong example... In my work, I need to compare rates of counts of charges deposits from different sources, taken with different exposure times, in order to have significant statistics. I wish to simply take the various charge deposits histograms and rescale each by its time. The log scale is because for small charges deposits I have like 10^4 counts, while for large deposits I have maybe 1-2 counts and I need to see also the tails of the distributions. What I do now is use `HistogramList` and rescale the second element of the list, then I use `ListPlot` to plot them.

Comment: I assume you'd want to compare "relative frequencies" rather than total counts.  If so, use the "PDF" option instead of the "LogCount" option.  But if you gave an example closer to the real data, that would be helpful.